# Etymology of the word "nerf"?

Tags: terminology

How did the word "nerf" develop to its current meaning in MMO/multiplayer games?

I can remember seeing it for a long time to have the same or similar meaning, even before the explosion of MMOs that happened with World of Warcraft.

(I used the terminology tag, as it seemed the closest fit, though I'm not actually asking what the word means.)

Comment: You might have some luck finding history of early usages of the term by asking on the [English language Stackexchange](http://english.stackexchange.com) site.

Comment: @Slothsberry: [It's actually already been asked.](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4221/buff-and-nurf-from-video-games-etymology)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Nerf has it's own [wiktionary entry](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nerf) (with the meaning "to water down, dumb down or especially weaken, particularly in the context of weapons in video games").

> **Etymology** From the Nerf brand of toys designed as non-dangerous counterparts of existing things, such as sports balls and guns.

Once powerful skills, tactics or strategies that have been rendered significantly less effective by changes in game mechanics are said to be "nerfed", as these once potent weapons have since been rendered as powerful as the foam toys.

Comment: Ironically a child at my little sister's daycare has had his eye __shot out__ by a nerf gun.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. :( Hasbro, the maker of Nerf products, does provide [safety information and eye protection with all of their products](http://www.ehow.com/facts_5784133_nerf-blaster-darts-safety.html). Unfortunately getting kids to follow those guidelines them is another matter.

Answer (score 7):

The word nerf is simply applying the proper noun of the company and product "NERF", which makes and sells air and spring powered guns using foam ammo.

So by saying a stat or character was "Nerfed" you're saying it has been given the same soft, less deadly "foam" coating as NERF applied to guns and ammo.

I'm not sure when it was first used, but it's origins have always been the NERF product.

Comment: Don't forget the foam swords and other melee weapons they have now.

Answer (score 6):

*[Nerf](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=nerf&searchmode=none)* was introduced as a trademark name for toys made of foam-like material for indoor play **in 1970** (*Nerf ball*).

The following [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nerf_%28computer_gaming%29) entry gives info about the term regarding computer gaming:

> In video gaming a nerf is a change to a game that reduces the
>   desirability or effectiveness of a particular game element. The term
>   is also used as a verb for the act of making such a change.The
>   opposite of nerf is buff (in one of that term's two usages).
>
> **The term originated with Ultima Online, and refers to the Nerf brand of toys which are soft and less likely to cause serious injury.** It
>   is used in the context of virtual worlds such as MMORPGs (like UO) and
>   MUDs, but has become a part of the general vocabulary of gamer slang
>   and can be found in various places where adjustment of power levels
>   from one version of a game to the next is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Nerf bars in offroading came first.  They called the foam padding 'nerf' before nerf was a brand.  Non Expanding Recreational Foam is one offering for what NERF may actually mean.

Comment: Can you cite a source for nerf bars predating the nerf toys?

Comment: > “Parker Brothers decided to name the balls NERF after the foam padding that off-road enthusiasts wrapped around their roll-bars.”  - (some interview the NERF Gun creators gave)[https://web.archive.org/web/20141103181756fw_/http://www.wedwabbit.com/reynGuyer/nerf.html]

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas, the context is all over the place. The statement is accurate - the creators said so in an interview. But this is about the actual NERF guns, not the word 'nerf' used in video games.

Comment: True but if you're tracing the history of a term you don't just give the last part, but start as far back as you can. Thanks for the link tho, i wasn't able to find anything when i googled nerf bars.